# remove & symbolic from Query

Tags: sql, oracle

we have Oracle query running in Informatica SQ transformation, I have given my query below

```
SELECT 
CAST(T.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('//text()') AS VARCHAR2(200))
FROM
    (SELECT regexp_replace('assaley&lee@direct.wvhin.org','(!@#$%^\&*()_+=)*','') as  RECIPIENTS FROM DUAL) T1,
    TABLE( xmlsequence( XMLTYPE( '<x><x>'  || REPLACE(t1.RECIPIENTS, ',', '</x><x>')  || '</x></x>' ).EXTRACT('//x/*'))) t


  where length(T1.RECIPIENTS) =28 -- and length(T1.RECIPIENTS) > 25
```

if i run this above query prompting some user input due '&' this symbolic reference, i should turnoff this prompt step.

could any one help me with this one?

Note: 'assaley&lee@direct.wvhin.org' this value is hard-coded value.

Thanks
Pandia

Comment: I'm not familiar with Informatica, but does it have an equivalent of SQL\*Plus' `set define off` command?

Comment: Yes that relevant to that function only but this query will run on the oracle only

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use UNISTR function and hardcode`&` as unicode literal: `\0026`:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm

```
SELECT unistr( 'assaley\0026lee@direct.wvhin.org' ) x
from dual;

X                          
----------------------------
assaley&lee@direct.wvhin.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the issue you are currently experiencing, the code should be corrected.

Within the regular expression you should use square brackets instead or round brackets.
Round brackets are intend for expression capturing.
Square brackets are intend for characters set.

```
SELECT  regexp_replace('assaley&lee@direct.wvhin.org','[!@#$%^\&*()_+=]+','') as  RECIPIENTS 
FROM    DUAL
;
```

Or -
remove anything except for letters and digits:

```
SELECT  regexp_replace('assaley&lee@direct.wvhin.org','[^[:alpha:][:digit:]]','') as  RECIPIENTS 
FROM    DUAL
;
```